# Run start-process with switch /netonly(Type-9 logon)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, authentication, cmd

Can i start-process with using switch /netonly (Type 9 logon), like can i use /netonly in below command.

```
"Start-Process powershell -Credential mydomain\mydomainAdmin -ArgumentList '-noprofile -command &{Start-Process notepad -verb runas}'"
```

Basically I logged in using admin account, i want to copy from some share where myaccount have the access. I want to use Type-9 logon(/netonly switch) with passing credential.

Using below command i am able to do it, but i have to input the password.

```
" runas /netonly /user:myadmin\myaccount "robocopy source destination" "
```

Please help to point right direction

Answer (score 0):

Using impersonation, you can do a netonly type logon using credentials which are defined in your script or somewhere else without the need of typing them every time.

(Please note than in this example, the `Write-host` when impersonated will not write a different username. This is specifically because of the New credentials logon type (INT 9) which impersonate the desired user when accessing remote resources only.)

```
$ImpersonationLib = Add-Type -Namespace 'Lib.Impersonation' -Name ImpersonationLib -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr token, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr duplication);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
"@ -PassThru
[System.IntPtr]$userToken = [System.IntPtr]::Zero
$success = $ImpersonationLib::LogonUser('YourUserName',      # UserName
                                    'DomainOrWorkstationNameIfLocal',       
# Domain
                                    'Password', #Password
                                    9, # New credentials-based logo
                                    0, # LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
                                    [ref]$userToken) 

if ($success -eq $false)
{
     Write-Host 'Failure to execute logon user.'
     Exit
}

$Identity = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity $userToken
# Close open handles.
if ($userToken -ne [System.IntPtr]::Zero)
{
  $null = $ImpersonationLib::CloseHandle($userToken)
  $userToken = [System.IntPtr]::Zero
}
# Current user.
Write-Host "Before impersonation: UserName: 
$([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
# Do the impersonation.
$context = $Identity.Impersonate()
# New user.
Write-Host "After impersonation: UserName: $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)" -ForegroundColor Cyan


# Return to original user.
$context.Undo()
$context.Dispose()
# Old user.
Write-Host "After undoing impersonation: UserName:     
$([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)"
```

Reference for logon types : [MSDN -Logon user function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I tried to implement but while copying in the context getting error "ERROR 1326 (0x0000052E) Accessing Source Directory,The user name or password is incorrect"   . I am inserting my copy command between the context "$context = $Identity.Impersonate()
# New user.
Write-Host "After impersonation: UserName: $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name)" -ForegroundColor Cyan

//copy command executed here
# Return to original user.
$context.Undo()"

Comment: If you omit your command and change only the username, password and domain to match one of your existing user, does it execute without error ?

Comment: Can you try changing the "9" value for "2" (it corresponds to interactive and run the script as is ? Normally, the 2 will work only locally, which means in the second write-host you should see the impersonated user. (this is for diagnostic purposes, just to confirm the basics works for you.)

Comment: Yes, if i omit my command, the script is running without any error.. but as it is not showing the proper username in the Write-host when the type is "9", i cannnot confirm which user script is running. I tried it by changing type "9" to "2", before inpersonation and after impersonation user name is showing same.. that is the target useraccount using which i want to run and provided in the script